# Как включить подробное логгирование на Symfony 4 в prod окружении

Tags: php, отладка, symfony, фреймворк

Симфония 4.4.51 , приложение реализующее api не работает при включенном prod окружении (`APP_ENV=prod`) и работает при переключении на dev окружение (меняю строку в .env.local) В prod окружении в ответ на http запросы возвращает 500 internal server error, при этом в лог var/log/prod.log ничего не кладет - уровень логирования на prod очень скудный.
**Как включить на prod более подробный уровень логирования?**
Скопировал config/packages/dev/monolog.yaml
в config/packages/prod/monolog.yaml сбросил кеш bin/console cache:clear но это не помогло.
Ну и в дополнение - может быть кто то сталкивался в чем может быть причина, что приложение обрабатывающее http запросы может работать на dev и не работать при переключении на prod?

Comment: например в композере вы прописал для пакета require-dev а на проде пытаетесь тоже использовать что-то из зависимостей